# ROS installation not working... or anything else

Tags: apt, package-management

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and am trying to install ROS Jade for work on a project. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have been following the steps listed at the [official website](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu). My repositories are configured as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCACE.png).

I follow the steps through 1.4 with no issues at all. However, when I try to run:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full
```

I receive the following error at the bottom of the results:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-jade-desktop-full : Depends: ros-jade-desktop but it is not going to  be installed
                     Depends: ros-jade-perception but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-jade-simulators but it is not going to be installed
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Now this is a fairly common problem, as I've found while searching around online. However, none of the solutions I found anywhere work. I did notice that the tutorial I linked suggests that dependency issues can be fixed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

However, this results in:

```
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic
```

Now, from here on out you'll have to excuse me as I am very inexperienced with this stuff and don't really know what I'm doing. I was obviously confused as to why nothing was working and tried a few more posted solutions. None worked. I then at some point read that ROS depends on something called Gazebo. Further research after has shown me that this may not be the case anymore, but at the time I tried installing Gazebo on the off chance this would work. I went to Gazebo's official tutorial and entered into my terminal:

```
curl -ssL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
```

And again got a similar result:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgazebo7-dev : Depends: libxml2-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqt4-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtwebkit-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libboost-all-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: freeglut3-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libogre-1.8-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libcurl4-openssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgts-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgdal-dev
              Depends: robot-player-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsdformat4-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsimbody-dev (>= 3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsimbody-dev (< 4.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libbullet2.82-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgazebo7 (= 7.0.0-1~trusty) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gazebo7-plugin-base (= 7.0.0-1~trusty)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Now perhaps I was really wrong in just going off and downloading Gazebo. But looking back, I seem to be getting errors for basically anything I try to install. This makes me wonder if there could be something wrong with my Ubuntu itself. Or perhaps I am messing up something simple in the process? Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. I don't believe this is a duplicate question as I could not find anything that addresses all three errors I am dealing with, but if there is an answered question like this, I apologize.